# Can Resharper produce an MSpec HTML report as well as the live Visual Studio test results?

Tags: resharper, mspec

I would like to have the live results in the ReSharper Test Results window and the custom formatted MSpec HTML report. Is that possible?

Comment: This is not a bad question and does not deserve downvotes or close votes without a comment. I've seen it elsewhere around SO (and will mark as duplicate if I can dig up a link).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly but you can export a unit test session run result to HTML:

[image]

Comment: I should also note that this export format is available since version 6.1

Comment: Thanks confirming that it won't run it for me, been looking everywhere for something that said it one way or another. I found the html output this way, but it didn't have the nice formatting that mspec provided through its html output. This will have to do for QA.

Answer (score 3):

First, gorohoroh's answer is correct (I've answered similar questions the same way). But, it sounds like you have a process where you want or have to deliver the last completed test results to the QA team. And you'd like to give them the fancy MSpec report (I'm a fan of that one, too).

Why not setup a continuous integration server that runs the build and tests and uses the native `mspec.exe` with the HTML report option (`--html`)?

Then, too, QA is not dependent on the results from a build on your personal workstation, but on a checked in version of the codebase.